# Crack stream cipher

Tags: encryption

I have a cipher. Message splits on parts with 8 bit length. Let part be $l[i]$. So encrypted part $l'[i] = l[i] \oplus r[i]$, where $r[i] = \text{low-orded 8 bits of $R[i]$}$, where
$$R[i] = ((a/R[i-1]) + 1)\bmod(n) \text.$$
If $R[i-1] == 0$ then $R[i] == 1$. $R[-1] == key$.
I have known params $a$, $n$, ciphered text.
How can I crack this algorithm? (I want to get a key.)

Comment: I think $n$ is better chosen prime, else $R[I-1]$ will too often become non-invertible. And, we need to know something about the plaintext to hope recover the key. The problem is under-specified (we do not even have the order of magnitude of $n$, or any idea of what's known about the plaintext), but it is not uninteresting. I find the close reason a tad off: there's no ciphertext, it it is not asked a review of that full (even if concise) cryptographic design. My main critic is that neither the statement nor the typography is polished enough; but we had much worse..